# Size UIView to UIViewController's view programmatically

Tags: swift, storyboard, uikit, autolayout

I'm trying to size a `UIView` to its superview. This works, except in the view that is automatically given in a Storyboard. So this code works for the `subview2` but the `subview` is not sized to its enclosing view.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithVFL(constraintsVFL: String, views: [String: UIView], metrics: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = nil, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions = NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros) {
        let mutableDict = (views as NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
        let constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(constraintsVFL, options: options, metrics: metrics, views: mutableDict)
        self.addConstraints(constraints)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var subview : UIView!  // red, inside self.view
    @IBOutlet var subview2 : UIView! // blue, inside subview

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var views : [String: UIView]
        views  = ["box": self.subview]//, "super": self.view]
        self.view.addConstraintsWithVFL("V:|-5-[box]-5-|", views: views)
        self.view.addConstraintsWithVFL("H:|-5-[box]-5-|", views: views)
        views  = ["box": self.subview2, "super": self.subview]
        self.view.addConstraintsWithVFL("V:|-5-[box]-5-|", views: views)
        self.view.addConstraintsWithVFL("H:|-5-[box]-5-|", views: views)
    }

}
```

Storyboard has no constraints anywhere in sight. Result looks like this:

[image]

How can I get my subview to size to the entire `UIView` using AutoLayout?

Comment: Sorry for the VFL code. I originally tried this with Cartography and got the same result.

Comment: Which view is which?  Is the red view `subView` or `subView2`?

Comment: subview is red, subview2 is blue. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when adding a view in IB, it's easier to add the constraint in IB, too. Then you simply don't have to deal with all the issues I'll enumerate below. But, if you're determined to create views in IB but add constraints programmatically, you should note:

1. In Xcode 6, if you don't add constraints in IB, it will create constraints for you. Select the red or blue view and then go to the size inspector <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. Under "Constraints" it may report the following if you don't have any constraints defined:

   > The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.
2. If you let Xcode add these constraints in addition to the ones you add programmatically, in Xcode 6 and later, you'd see warnings like the following:

   > 2015-02-14 21:44:59.766 AutoLayoutTest[22382:8773715] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
   >
   > Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
   >
   > ```
   > ( 
   >     "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5a9c94770 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff5a9c926c0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff5a9c93360 )>",
   >     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5a9c99400 H:|-(5)-[UIView:0x7ff5a9c926c0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff5a9c93360 )>"
   > )
   > ```
   >
   > Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
   >
   > Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
   >   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

   Xcode 5, though, will not add these constraints for you.
3. If you're determined to add constraints programmatically for views that you're not creating programmatically, in Xcode 6 you should add your own constraints to the views (e.g. the "Reset to suggested constraints" option, if you want it to create a full set for you) in IB:

   [image]

   Then go through all of the individual constraints and flag them to be removed at build time:

   [image]
4. Alternatively, if you want to programmatically remove the IB generated constraints before adding your own, you could do something like:

   ```
   removeConstraintsBetweenFirstItem(view, secondItem: redView)
   removeConstraintsBetweenFirstItem(redView, secondItem: blueView)
   ```

   Where

   ```
   func removeConstraintsBetweenFirstItem(firstItem: UIView, secondItem: UIView) {
       let constraintsToRemove = firstItem.constraints().filter() { (constraint) -> (Bool) in
           if constraint.firstItem as UIView == secondItem {  // in Swift 1.2, use as!
               return true
           }
           if let constraintSecondItem = constraint.secondItem as? UIView {
               return constraintSecondItem == secondItem
           }
           return false
       }
       firstItem.removeConstraints(constraintsToRemove)
   }
   ```

   This is safer than just doing the following, which is a little more indiscriminate than I prefer:

   ```
   view.removeConstraints(view.constraints())
   redView.removeConstraints(redView.constraints())
   ```
5. Having done that, you can now programmatically add your constraints, as you outlined:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let views = ["redView" : redView, "blueView" : blueView]
       view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[redView]-5-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
       view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-5-[redView]-5-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
       redView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[blueView]-5-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
       redView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-5-[blueView]-5-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
   }
   ```

   That yields the following result, with no untoward warnings:

   [image]
6. If you want to to diagnose your constraints, you can run the app and then click on the view debugger:

   [image]

   Alternatively, you can pause execution of the app and at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter

   ```
   po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
   ```

   Through either one of these techniques, you can diagnose the constraints that you've added to your view.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! It also works with `redView.removeConstraints(redView.constraints())` instead of `remove at build time`. However: **if there are no constraints placed in IB, this does not work. Any way to avoid putting in any constraints in IB?**

Comment: Yep, you can remove constraints programmatically (though I prefer to filter the constraints and remove only those that match my criteria). But, for me, if I can have IB remove them for me automatically at build time (via that "placeholder" feature) rather than manually at run-time, I prefer that. In terms of having IB not add these default constraints at all, no, I'm not familiar with any way to do that (though I wish we could).

Comment: Sorry, I meant: if I don't place any constraints myself, the whole scheme doesn't work. Why might this be? (I thought that removing all constraints would be the same as not adding any constraints). Thanks!

Comment: I get what you want, but, annoying, it's just not how it works. If you don't place any constraints in IB, IB will graciously add a bunch for you and you can't stop it (lol). The only way to have no constraints added at build-time is, ironically, to explicitly tell IB to add all the default constraints it wants, and then go through them all, one-by-one, and tell IB to "remove at build time". Or don't add any, let Xcode add a bunch at build time, and then programmatically remove them at run-time. It's annoying, but those are the choices.

Comment: (Obviously, you can add the views programmatically, rather than IB, and you don't have to deal with this. Or, if you add the views in IB, add the real constraints in IB, too, and you don't have to deal with this silliness.)

Comment: In this one case (adding a view to a `UIViewController`'s view) I cannot do it correctly in code at all. Hmmm....

Comment: If you want to upload it somewhere and share the link here and I'd be happy to take a look. You definitely _can_ do it, so I suspect its something simple.

Comment: Thank you, no worries, I've gotten it all working perfectly in code. Also good to know that you need to add constraints to not have constraints in IB ;)